# Javascript scroll to element on scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll

I searched very long but haven't found a soulution yet.

I want to scroll to the next element on scroll.

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var scroll = false;

  $(function() {
    //Create an Array
    var sites = $('.site');
    var position = 0; //Start Position
    var next = $('#next');
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
      if(scroll == false){
            scroll = true;
            $(document).off('scroll');
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop){
              if (position !== sites.length - 1) {
                scrollToPosition(sites[position += 1]),5000;
              }
            } else {
              if (position !== 0) {
                scrollToPosition(sites[position -= 1]),5000;
              }
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
          }
        });
      })

    function scrollToPosition(element) {
      if (element !== undefined) {
        scrollToElement($(element).attr('id'));
      }
    }

    function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
      time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
      verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
      selector = "#" + selector;
      var element = $(selector);
      offset = element.offset();
      offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, time);
      scroll = false;
    }
  });
```

the html has many of these with different ids

```
<div id="test" style="width:100%; height:100vh;" class="site">

</div>
```

So the containers are fullscreen hight. and when the user scrolls a bit he should get to the next container.
At the moment it scrolls till the end and or more.

Comment: careful, if your HTML has many `<div>`s of the same ID then it will not pass the validator and you may run into trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could create an example in jsFiddle or CodePen, but the first thing I would do is stop any current jQuery animations before launching new ones:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: offsetTop
}, time);
```

You should keep in mind that scroll handler is executed many times when user is scrolling.

Also, unrelated - your scrollToPosition calls have brackets at the wrong place and should probably be like this:

```
scrollToPosition(sites[position += 1], 5000);
```

Edit:

Another thing that might cause problems - you should unset the 'scroll' flag/variable only when the animation has finished, something like this:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: offsetTop
}, time, function () {
    scroll = false;
});
```